# Why significate MySQL Error Galera cluster?

Tags: mysql, galera

I'm trying to join a Galera Cluster and I'm getting this error:

```
2023-09-19T22:46:03.068834Z 0 \[ERROR\] WSREP: failed to open gcomm backend connection: 110: failed to reach primary view: 110 (Connection timed out)
at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():160
2023-09-19T22:46:03.068858Z 0 \[ERROR\] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():209: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
2023-09-19T22:46:03.069136Z 0 \[ERROR\] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1458: Failed to open channel 'zabbix_data_cluster' at 'ip1,ip2,ip3': -110 (Connection timed out)
2023-09-19T22:46:03.069150Z 0 \[ERROR\] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
2023-09-19T22:46:03.069155Z 0 \[ERROR\] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://ip1,ip2,ip3) failed: 7
2023-09-19T22:46:03.069163Z 0 \[ERROR\] Aborting
```

What should I do?